# thinning/skeletonization algorithm with 4 known neighbors

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am searching for a thinning/skeletonization algorithm which works if I only know 4 neighbors not 8.
From all algorithms I could find I assume that I have knowledge about the diagonal neighbors.

So does anybody know about a thinning algorithm which also works if I only know the top, right, bottom, left neighbor?

The outcome should be like this:
http://www.cs.ru.nl/~ths/rt2/col/h9/thinning.GIF

These are not what I am looking for:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Skel.png/220px-Skel.png
The shape should be maintained as in the first example

Comment: I'm sure there are several standart approaches, but what about "Delete all black cells adjacent to 1 white cell or several white cells divided by at most 4 steps of BFS (using just white space)" ? 7-10 iterations of this algorithm may solve your problem.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand correctly. I stumble oevr this part "or several white cells divided by at most 4 steps of BFS". How do you prevent ends like in the first example to get deleted?

Comment: it wasn't good idea (it need to be developed at least), I've tried it and got ugly results 
http://i.imgbox.com/V9DTA0IQ.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/IkclhkM3.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/Vy2gSwrs.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/kyZIL7ZP.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/pjj9iVOd.jpg
http://i.imgbox.com/XYbNvxOp.jpg
And my another idea of BFS + A* failing too. 
http://i.imgbox.com/bGJX6OxB.png
It's better to know about 8 neighbours, not 4...

Comment: BTW, mb you should try to get some info about 4 neighbours first, and get info about their neighbours which is adjacent to starting cell by diagonal. And you'll get info about 8 neighbours, not 4.

Comment: BTW2, mb you shouldn't solve this problem for general case. If your interest is english letters - it may be easier to design smth working specially for them.

Comment: The use case is not restricted to bitmaps where i can gather information to know 8 neighbors after iterations. The use case is exactly that each "cell" always only knows about 4 neighbors. The algorithm can work in iterations but only based on this knowledge. Infact it is kind of a graph structure. My restrictions written in the post still work though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using one of the 8-neighbour algorithms, but feeding it dummy information for the diagonal cells or otherwise modifying the part of the algorithm that considers neighbours.

Since you're not too specific about the kinds of things you're looking at it's hard to offer concrete suggestions. Most algorithms will contain a part that looks like this:

```
for n in neighbours:
  do stuff
```

in which case you need to edit `neighbours`.

Others will apply some kind of mask or kernel function. Edit that kernel.